# Populating a dropdown list using a for loop in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know it is not the best practice to do this, but I am curious on how you would populate a `dropdownlist` using a `for` loop in razor.

I am trying to do it this way

```
@{
      int year = DateTime.Now.Year;

      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ResolutionYear, new List<SelectListItem>
      {
          for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          {
              if (year - i == year)
              {
                  new SelectListItem() { Text = (year - i).ToString(), Value = (year - i).ToString(), Selected = true };
              }
              else
              {
                  new SelectListItem() { Text = (year - i).ToString(), Value = (year - i).ToString() };
              }
          }
        })
}
```

It doesn't seem to like the way I am doing it as it keeps shouting at me `} expected` I have all all the closing brackets for each open bracket. Perhaps I am populating my `DropDownList` wrong? Is it even possible to populate this way or should I just do it in the controller?

Comment: I think you already know this is not valid C# syntax, but why arent you doing this logic in your controller and passing a `List<SelectListItem>` in your ViewModel?

Comment: You are populating your list wrong, or at least badly. Why have you chosen to do it this way?

Comment: I was populating it with static years in the razor code, but was curious to know if I could do it with a for loop to ensure that the only 10 years prior to the current year is displayed...It was more of a curiosity question then anything

Comment: Not good practice, but the following will work: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ResolutionYear, new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Today.Year - 10, 10)));` The controller is responsible for generating the data and sending it to the view

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it. Keep your Views as benign as possible. Use your View Model and Controller, that's what they're for. But for curiosity's sake, here's one way:

```
@{ var year = DateTime.Now.Year; }
<select>
@for (var i = year; (i > year - 10); i--)
{
    if (i == (year - 3))
    {
        <option value="@i" selected>@i</option>
    }
    else
    {
        <option value="@i">@i</option>
    }
}
</select>
```